# Should exceptions thrown in UI thread but originating in another thread raise UI ThreadException?

Tags: .net, multithreading, exception

*Note: this is conceptual framework question, not VB.Net-specific question. Can be asked in C#, too.*

I have added the following handler at application startup:

```
AddHandler System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException, AddressOf UIThreadException
```

It works just fine and handler gets every exception

**except the case when** I pass the call from my custom background thread (queue processing) into main thread using standard `System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Send()`. Execution is then carried successfully in main thread but **any exception thrown never triggers the above handler** and unhandled exception is thrown.

Do you have any experience, is this expected behavior of the framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the Send(...) method.

Looking at the source:

```
// Summary:
//     When overridden in a derived class, dispatches a synchronous message to a
//     synchronization context.
// Parameters:
//   d:
//     The System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback delegate to call.
//   state:
//     The object passed to the delegate.
public virtual void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state);
```

This method works synchronous, so it's basically handled inside the thread.
But we can take a look at the Post(...) method.

```
// Summary:
//     When overridden in a derived class, dispatches an asynchronous message to
//     a synchronization context.
// Parameters:
//   d:
//     The System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback delegate to call.
//   state:
//     The object passed to the delegate.
public virtual void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state);
```

This means that Post will not wait for the execution of the delegate to complete. Post will "Fire and Forget" about the execution code within the delegate. It also means that you cannot catch exceptions as we did with the Send method. Suppose an exception is thrown, it will be the UI thread that will get it; unhandling the exception will terminate the UI thread.

Additional Information here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31971/Understanding-SynchronizationContext-Part-I

Comment: @Miroxlav Here's an additional link. Maybe you finde there additional information: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31971/Understanding-SynchronizationContext-Part-I

Comment: Thank you, the answer nailed the problem.